# Dependencies are not injected in tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, junit5

I have the following repository:

```
package com.spring.domain.repository;

import com.spring.domain.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String> {
}
```

And I'm trying to create a simple integration test for my application, for which I need to inject the repository:

```
package com.spring.integration;

import com.spring.domain.repository.ProductRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class IntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

}
```

But I don't know how to do it properly, since `productRepository` is always `null`.

Spring Boot version is 1.5.14.RELEASE

Comment: use `@DataJpaTest`

Comment: Wild guess, mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5 annotations on the same class. Also the `@Repository` is useless on a Spring Data interface.

Comment: @Jens This is not a repository test. Is an integration test for which I need the repository to insert data in the db prior to the test execution

Comment: @M.Deinum what am I mixing?

Comment: JUnit 5 and JUnit4 annotations. It looks like your class is for Junit5 (as it isn't public) but I guess the `@Test` you are importing is from JUnit4 `org.junit` package. Which  renders the `@SpringBootTest` annotation rather useless as it won't bootstrap nor inject anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum these are my imports: 
`import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;`

Comment: Please don't add them as comments, instead edit your code and please add the full test (including hte package and imports) instead of a snippet which doesn't really expose what you are doing. Also please clarify which Spring Boot version you are using.

Comment: Spring Boot 1.5 doesn't add the `@ExtendWith` on `@SpringBootTest`. Either add `@ExtendWIth(SpringExtension.class)` to your test or upgrade to a newer Spring Boot version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing test properties/yaml and test DB(for testing we usually use h2 database)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@SpringBootTest(SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK,
  classes = Application.class)

@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-integrationtest.properties")
```

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing